# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body help/h.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord-buttons

It says invalid Form Body and I can't fine the error when I keep trying tactics.

const { MessageActionRow, MessageSelectMenu, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { prefix } = require("../../config.json");

const commandsEmbedsColor = "SOMETHING";

module.exports = {
name: 'help',
aliases: ["h", "commands", "cmd", "cmds"],
utilisation: '{prefix}test',

```
async execute(client, message, args) {
  
  const row = new MessageActionRow()
          .addComponents(
              new MessageSelectMenu()
                .setCustomId('select')
                .setPlaceholder('Click here to Select a Command Category!')
                .addOptions([
                      {
                          label: 'Fun',
                        description: 'Shows a list of Fun Commands.',
                          value: '1',
            emoji: "",
                      },
          {
                          label: 'Games',
                        description: 'Shows a list of Games Commands.',
                          value: '2',
            emoji: "",
                      },
          {
                          label: 'General',
                        description: 'Shows a list of General Commands.',
                          value: '3',
            emoji: "",
                      },
          {
                          label: 'Image',
                        description: 'Shows a list of Image Commands.',
                          value: '4',
            emoji: "",
                      },
          {
                          label: 'Information',
                        description: 'Shows a list of Info Commands.',
                          value: '5',
            emoji: "ℹ️",
                      },
          {
                          label: 'Minecraft',
                        description: 'Shows a list of Minecraft Commands.',
                          value: '6',
            emoji: "955440066321322004",
                      },
          {
                          label: 'Moderation',
                        description: 'Shows a list of Moderation Commands.',
                          value: '7',
            emoji: "⚒",
                      },
          {
                          label: 'Utility',
                        description: 'Shows a list of Utility Commands.',
                          value: '8',
            emoji: "⚙️",
                      },
                  ]),
          );
  const embedMenu = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
    .setTitle(client.user.username + " - Help Menu:")
    .setDescription(`Hey ${message.author}, Thanks for using **${client.user.username}** for today! Select the commands category from the select menu below.`)
    .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor("GREEN");

    await message.reply({ embeds: [embedMenu], components: [row/*, buttons*/] });

  // If you want to add more commands, use this template below in the ".addFields( ... )" code:
  // { name: "• ", value: `\`${prefix}\``, inline: true },

  const embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
    .setTitle("Fun Commands:")
    .addFields(
      { name: "• 8ball", value: `\`${prefix}8ball\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• random_color", value: `\`${prefix}randomc\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• random_number", value: `\`${prefix}randomn\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• ship", value: `\`${prefix}ship\``, inline: true },
    )
    .setColor(commandsEmbedsColor);

  const embed2 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
    .setTitle("Games Commands:")
    .addFields(
      { name: "• find_the_number", value: `\`${prefix}number\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• secret_number", value: `\`${prefix}sn\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• youtube_together", value: `\`${prefix}ytt\``, inline: true },
    )
    .setColor(commandsEmbedsColor);

  const embed3 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
    .setTitle("General Commands:")
    .addFields(
      { name: "• avatar", value: `\`${prefix}av\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• ping", value: `\`${prefix}ping\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• server_icon", value: `\`${prefix}servericon\``, inline: true },
    )
    .setColor(commandsEmbedsColor);

  const embed4 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
    .setTitle("Image Commands:")
    .addFields(
      { name: "• meme", value: `\`${prefix}meme\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• troll", value: `\`${prefix}troll\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• yt_comment", value: `\`${prefix}ytc\``, inline: true },
    )
    .setColor(commandsEmbedsColor);

  const embed5 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
    .setTitle("Info Commands:")
    .addFields(
      { name: "• help", value: `\`${prefix}h\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• member_count", value: `\`${prefix}memberc\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• role_info", value: `\`${prefix}rolei\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• server_info", value: `\`${prefix}serveri\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• uptime", value: `\`${prefix}up\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• user_id", value: `\`${prefix}userid\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• user_info", value: `\`${prefix}useri\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• warnings", value: `\`${prefix}warns\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• weather", value: `\`${prefix}weather\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• yt_search", value: `\`${prefix}ytse\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• yt_stats", value: `\`${prefix}ytst\``, inline: true },
    )
    .setColor(commandsEmbedsColor);

  const embed6 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
    .setTitle("Minecraft Commands:")
    .addFields(
      { name: "• achievement", value: `\`${prefix}ach\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• skin", value: `\`${prefix}skin\``, inline: true },
    )
    .setColor(commandsEmbedsColor);

  const embed7 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
    .setTitle("Moderation Commands:")
    .addFields(
      { name: "• ban", value: `\`${prefix}b\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• dm", value: `\`${prefix}dm\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• kick", value: `\`${prefix}k\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• mute", value: `\`${prefix}m\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• nick", value: `\`${prefix}n\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• purge", value: `\`${prefix}p\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• remove_timeout", value: `\`${prefix}rtm\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• remove_warning", value: `\`${prefix}rw\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• role_add", value: `\`${prefix}ra\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• role_remove", value: `\`${prefix}rm\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• slowmode", value: `\`${prefix}sm\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• timeout", value: `\`${prefix}tm\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• unmute", value: `\`${prefix}unm\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• warn", value: `\`${prefix}w\``, inline: true },
    )
    .setColor(commandsEmbedsColor);

  const embed8 = new MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor({ name: client.user.username, iconURL: client.user.displayAvatarURL() })
    .setTitle("Utility Commands:")
    .addFields(
      { name: "• calculate", value: `\`${prefix}calc\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• dropdown_role", value: `\`${prefix}r\``, inline: true },
      { name: "• suggest", value: `\`${prefix}suggest\``, inline: true },
    )
    .setColor(commandsEmbedsColor);

  const collector = message.channel.createMessageComponentCollector({
    componentType: "SELECT_MENU"
  })

  collector.on("collect", async (collected) => {

    const value = collected.values[0]

    if(value === "1"){
      collected.reply({ embeds: [embed1], ephemeral: true }).catch(err => console.log("[Error Handled]"));
    }

    if(value === "2"){
      collected.reply({ embeds: [embed2], ephemeral: true }).catch(err => console.log("[Error Handled]"));
    }

    if(value === "3"){
      collected.reply({ embeds: [embed3], ephemeral: true }).catch(err => console.log("[Error Handled]"));
    }

    if(value === "4"){
      collected.reply({ embeds: [embed4], ephemeral: true }).catch(err => console.log("[Error Handled]"));
    }

    if(value === "5"){
      collected.reply({ embeds: [embed5], ephemeral: true }).catch(err => console.log("[Error Handled]"));
    }

    if(value === "6"){
      collected.reply({ embeds: [embed6], ephemeral: true }).catch(err => console.log("[Error Handled]"));
    }

    if(value === "7"){
      collected.reply({ embeds: [embed7], ephemeral: true }).catch(err => console.log("[Error Handled]"));
    }

    if(value === "8"){
      collected.reply({ embeds: [embed8], ephemeral: true }).catch(err => console.log("[Error Handled]"));
    }
    
  })
    
},
```

};

Rewrite the code 5 times.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).